# I have a code for twitter sentiment analysis and I want to export the result to csv file

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, csv

This is what I get: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6SOFM.png)

This is the code how can I export the output to csv file from python console?

that's important for me.

======================================================================================================================================================

```
import re
import tweepy
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from textblob import TextBlob

class TwitterClient(object):
    '''
    Generic Twitter Class for sentiment analysis.
    '''
    def __init__(self):
        '''
        Class constructor or initialization method.
        '''
        # keys and tokens from the Twitter Dev Console
        consumer_key = '???'
        consumer_secret = '???'
        access_token = '???'
        access_token_secret = '???'

        # attempt authentication
        try:
            # create OAuthHandler object
            self.auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
            # set access token and secret
            self.auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
            # create tweepy API object to fetch tweets
            self.api = tweepy.API(self.auth)
        except:
            print("Error: Authentication Failed")

    def clean_tweet(self, tweet):
        '''
        Utility function to clean tweet text by removing links, special characters
        using simple regex statements.
        '''
        return ' '.join(re.sub("(@[A-Za-z0-9]+)|([^0-9A-Za-z \t])|(\w+:\/\/\S+)", " ", tweet).split())

    def get_tweet_sentiment(self, tweet):
        '''
        Utility function to classify sentiment of passed tweet
        using textblob's sentiment method
        '''
        # create TextBlob object of passed tweet text
        analysis = TextBlob(self.clean_tweet(tweet))
        # set sentiment
        if analysis.sentiment.polarity > 0:
            return 'positive'
        elif analysis.sentiment.polarity == 0:
            return 'neutral'
        else:
            return 'negative'

    def get_tweets(self, query, count = 10):
        '''
        Main function to fetch tweets and parse them.
        '''
        # empty list to store parsed tweets
        tweets = []

        try:
            # call twitter api to fetch tweets
            fetched_tweets = self.api.search(q = query, count = count)

            # parsing tweets one by one
            for tweet in fetched_tweets:
                # empty dictionary to store required params of a tweet
                parsed_tweet = {}

                # saving text of tweet
                parsed_tweet['text'] = tweet.text
                # saving sentiment of tweet
                parsed_tweet['sentiment'] = self.get_tweet_sentiment(tweet.text)

                # appending parsed tweet to tweets list
                if tweet.retweet_count > 0:
                    # if tweet has retweets, ensure that it is appended only once
                    if parsed_tweet not in tweets:
                        tweets.append(parsed_tweet)
                else:
                    tweets.append(parsed_tweet)

            # return parsed tweets
            return tweets

        except tweepy.TweepError as e:
            # print error (if any)
            print("Error : " + str(e))




def main():
    # creating object of TwitterClient Class
    api = TwitterClient()
    # calling function to get tweets
    tweets = api.get_tweets(query = 'Donald Trump', count = 200)

    # picking positive tweets from tweets
    ptweets = [tweet for tweet in tweets if tweet['sentiment'] == 'positive']
    # percentage of positive tweets
    print("Positive tweets percentage: {} %".format(100*len(ptweets)/len(tweets)))
    # picking negative tweets from tweets
    ntweets = [tweet for tweet in tweets if tweet['sentiment'] == 'negative']
    # percentage of negative tweets
    print("Negative tweets percentage: {} %".format(100*len(ntweets)/len(tweets)))
    # percentage of neutral tweets
#    print("Neutral tweets percentage: {} %".format(100*len(tweets - ntweets - ptweets)/len(tweets)))

    # printing first 5 positive tweets
    print("\n\nPositive tweets:")
    for tweet in ptweets[:10]:
        print(tweet['text'])



    # printing first 5 negative tweets
    print("\n\nNegative tweets:")
    for tweet in ntweets[:10]:
        print(tweet['text'])





if __name__ == "__main__":
    # calling main function
    main()
```

pleas help to solve it, thanks..

Comment: what are you trying to export to a csv?

Comment: the result, I put the image for the result.

Comment: the question still stands. are you trying to export everything in your image?

Comment: Please check [how to ask question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) 
Please remove the `ssssssssssssssssssssssss.................``

Comment: Do not include images of text.

Comment: how do you want to save the data to a csv file?

Comment: @Primusa 
yes dear, I want to export output.

Comment: @shahaf  I don't know just I want to export it I have a headache from this problem, if there is no solution logically tell me please.

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv

tweets = [{'sentiment' : 'positive', 'text' : 'some text'}, {'sentiment' : 'negative', 'text' : 'some other text'}]

with open('tweets.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    fieldnames = ['sentiment', 'text']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows(tweets)
```

Comment: What a genius you are!!
The code is work and do what I want, but still I have a small problem, the output gets:

 return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]

UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 89-90: character maps to <undefined>


What's the problem?!

Comment: Ok, I solve it and its work perfect!!
Thanks again and again and again my friend @shahaf .